# IndexError: list index out of range, face_recognition

Tags: python, opencv, face-recognition, index-error

I am using open cv and face recognition together, however this line of code:

```
biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
```

is giving me the following error:

```
IndexError: list index out of range
```

I have read up on this error and most conclude that it means that face_recognition is not detecting any faces in the frame. **However**, open cv is detecting faces within that **same frame**, so I am not sure if face_recognition is indeed not detecting any faces or I am receiving an IndexError for some other reason?

all the code needed to get a background of the issue:

```
check, frame = video.read()
faceCascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier(
    'C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\face detection software\\data\\haarcascade_frontalface_alt.xml')

frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)

faces = faceCascade.detectMultiScale(
    frame,
    scaleFactor=1.2,
    minNeighbors=5,
)

for x, y, w, h in faces:
    img = cv2.rectangle(frame, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 0, 0), 1)

    if len(os.listdir("C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\face detection software\\saved faces\\")) == 0:

        cv2.imwrite(
            "C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\face detection software\\saved faces\\" + "1 faces.jpg", cropped)
    else:
        cv2.imwrite(
            "C:\\Users\\Astroid\Desktop\\face detection software\\unknown faces\\" + " unknown_faces.jpg", cropped)

        known_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(
            "C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\face detection software\\saved faces\\" + "1 faces.jpg")

        unknown_image = face_recognition.load_image_file(
           "C:\\Users\\Astroid\Desktop\\face detection software\\unknown faces\\" + " unknown_faces.jpg"

        biden_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
        print(biden_encoding)#

        unknown_encoding = face_recognition.face_encodings(unknown_image)[0]
        print(unknown_encoding)#

        results = face_recognition.compare_faces([biden_encoding], [unknown_encoding])

        if results >= (60):
            shutil.move(
                "C:\\Users\\Astroid\Desktop\\face detection software\\unknown faces\\" + " unknown_faces.jpg",
                "C:\\Users\\Astroid\\Desktop\\face detection software\\saved faces\\" + (face_num) + (" faces.jpg"))
        else:
            pass
```

Comment: You wanna show the rest of the code my man?

Comment: What do you get when you print `face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)` ?

Comment: the logistics of the code is that open-cv detects a face within a frame of a live video feed, opencv then crops the frame in on to that face and saves it as a .jpg, face-recognition then loads that .jpg into the software and draws ".face_encodings" for the loaded image and an incoming image from the next frame and compares the two encodings to check if the face is the same face. ill lode the necessary code into the question in a sec.

Comment: to answer arsho's question i get a list of numbers, which is why im so confused about this error

Comment: just note that i did cut allot of stuff out of the code that was not related to the issue so the code may not run...

Answer (score 4):

This means that the `face_recognition` module couldn't find any faces in the image. `face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)` basically returns a list of all the faces found in the photo. Now, you are using the index `[0]` to get the first found face. However, when there is no face in the image, you are trying to get a non-existent index, hence the `IndexError`.

The only real solution to this is to use a new image. `face_recognition` cannot find any faces, so either you can make your own algorithm to find a face, which I highly do not recommend, or you use a different image.

Answer (score 1):

It means, the `dlib` face detector couldn't detect a face in the image you passed in. You could add a try exception block something like this:

```
try:
    image_to_be_matched_encoded = face_recognition.face_encodings(known_image)[0]
except IndexError as e:
    print(e)
    sys.exit(1) # stops code execution in my case you could handle it differently
```

More on this can be found here:  https://github.com/ageitgey/face_recognition/issues/100#issuecomment-307590846

Answer (score 1):

i solve that problem by changing the images to jpeg, it means you should include a clean quality of such an image with jpeg type, Regards

Answer (score 0):

I was loading an **animated image** (it was in .jpg format, but animated image), hence I was getting this error. I changed the image to regular non-animated image, and this time same code worked without any errors.